# Alterando matriz de inteiros para filtro de imagem

Tags: c, matriz, filtro

Estou fazendo um programa que aplica filtros em imagens `.ppm`, imagens sem nenhuma codificação, o problema é que quando eu aplico os filtros, a imagem original não está se alterando, onde está meu erro?

A mesma coisa está acontecendo para os outros filtros.

[Mais sobre imagens PPM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format)

```
  /* 
 * File:   main.c
 * Author: pmargreff
 *
 * Created on 11 de Novembro de 2014, 00:10
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/*
 * 
 */

typedef struct {
    int r;
    int g;
    int b;
} pixel;

pixel imagem[300][300];


void filtro_negativo(pixel im[300][300], int alt, int larg, int max);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int alt, larg;
    char tipo[3];
    char coment[100];
    int max;
    int i, j;

    scanf("%s%d%d%d", tipo, &larg, &alt, &max);

    for (i = 0; i < alt; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < larg; j++) {
            scanf("%d%d%d", &imagem[i][j].r, &imagem[i][j].g, &imagem[i][j].b);
        }
    }

    filtro_negativo(imagem, alt, larg, max);

    printf("%s\n", tipo);
    printf("%d %d\n", larg, alt);
    printf("%d\n", max);

    for (i = 0; i < alt; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < larg; j++) {
            printf("%d %d %d\n", 255 - imagem[i][j].r, 255 - imagem[i][j].g, 255 - imagem[i][j].b);
        }
    }
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void filtro_negativo(pixel im[300][300], int alt, int larg, int max) {
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < alt; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < larg; j++) {
            im[i][j].r = max - im[i][j].r;
            im[i][j].g = max - im[i][j].g;
            im[i][j].b = max - im[i][j].b;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O seu código funciona (muito embora exista alguns potenciais problemas, como por exemplo a largura e altura da imagem serem passadas por parâmetro mas estarem fixas no código na definição do array `imagem`), e a sua imagem é alterada de acordo com o seu "filtro". O problema é que na hora de reexibir os dados da sua imagem você desfaz a aplicação do filtro subtraindo novamente o valor 255 do valor de cada componente no pixel.

Fiz um exemplo mais curto (e que não lê os dados do stdin) pra facilitar a observação desse problema ([dá pra executar o código no Ideone](http://ideone.com/tljcbM)):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    int r;
    int g;
    int b;
} pixel;

pixel imagem[2][2];

void filtro_negativo(pixel im[2][2], int alt, int larg, int max);

int main(void) {

    imagem[0][0].r = 1; imagem[0][0].g = 1; imagem[0][0].b = 1;
    imagem[0][1].r = 2; imagem[0][1].g = 2; imagem[0][1].b = 2;
    imagem[1][0].r = 3; imagem[1][0].g = 3; imagem[1][0].b = 3;
    imagem[1][1].r = 4; imagem[1][1].g = 4; imagem[1][1].b = 4;

    printf("Antes:\n");
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            printf("%d %d %d\n", imagem[i][j].r, imagem[i][j].g, imagem[i][j].b);
        }
    }   

    filtro_negativo(imagem, 2, 2, 4);

    printf("Depois:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            printf("%d %d %d\n", imagem[i][j].r, imagem[i][j].g, imagem[i][j].b);
        }
    }

    printf("Depois (exibindo errado):\n");
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            printf("%d %d %d\n", 4 - imagem[i][j].r, 4 - imagem[i][j].g, 4 - imagem[i][j].b);
        }
    }       

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);  
}

void filtro_negativo(pixel im[2][2], int alt, int larg, int max) {
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < alt; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < larg; j++) {
            im[i][j].r = max - im[i][j].r;
            im[i][j].g = max - im[i][j].g;
            im[i][j].b = max - im[i][j].b;
        }
    }
}
```

Resultando em:

```
Antes:
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4
Depois:
3 3 3
2 2 2
1 1 1
0 0 0
Depois (exibindo errado):
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4
```

P.S.: Note que no exemplo eu usei o valor `4` como "máximo" ao invés de `255` (apenas para ilustrar).